# Algorithm counting

Tags: python, algorithm

I am a bit confused in this condition: lets say we have a number from 1 to 9 its numerical code from the beginning 1 to the 9. If the number already reach number 9, then it is loop again from 1 to 9 again, and it begin again from number 1. Each number from that range **continue appear with a random number continue** like this example:

> 1111122222333334444445555556666667777777888888999999111111222222333333444445555566677778899....

then the problem is I need an algorithm or a code to detect if *number 4* appear I want count it as 1, but I want to eliminate the continue appear from the number 4 other (I didnt want to count the continuing of number 4). sorry if its not a clearly explaination. It maybe better explain from the example. the example:
if the data is

> 111122233**4**445556667788999111222333**4**44455566677788899

so the counting program must be 2 because number 4 appear **twice** (I mark the first appear of number 4), and the continuing for that number not be count. oh yes all of that number (1-9) it always continue appear with a random number continue.

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: your question really does not make much sense, if english is not your first language maybe a few more examples would help.

Comment: As far as I understand you need to count how many runs of a chosen digit appear in a given string—is that correct?

Comment: It does seem a bit harsh to mark the OP down so severely when it only takes a few seconds to check their other posts! Just because they don't speak perfect English.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham: sorry, I have added the example in there. for the more details here: we have number series from 1 to 9, after it   already reach number 9 it begin again from 1 to 9 and so on. but each number have repeatedly appears (the repeater is depend on a randomly condition) like this 12233444555667899112233.. (and so forth). if I need to count the ONLY the first number of 4 (I dont want to count the repeatedly appears) so the count in the example is 1 not 3 (the repeatly 4 appears thrice (444), is it clear?

Comment: @ CiaPan: yes like that but I dont want count the repeatedly appears of that number, only the first number of that repeatedly appears I want to count as one.

Comment: @ paddyg: sorry, if my english language so bad. Is it clear question for you? I will repeat if its still unclear. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If the number appear at least once you could count the "edges" ie

```
n = numstr.count("34")
```

(Obviously need to test starting number in sequence as special case (i.e. if looking at number of "91"s)

EDIT. Following significant revision mentioned in comments, you would have to do something along the lines of this:

```
a = [66,69,69,77,78,80,84,84,91,91,96,96,100,100,109,116,116,124,124,137,137,140,66,66,66,78,78,80,80,80,84]
c = {a[0]:1}
for i in range(1, len(a)):
  if a[i] != a[i-1]:
    if a[i] in c:
      c[a[i]] += 1
    else:
      c[a[i]] = 1
```

Comment: How about counting digit "1", whose first appearing is not preceded by "9"...?

Comment: I run that program but it present an error about numstr not defined. sorry can you detailed the code?

Comment: numstr = "1111222334445556667788999111222333444455566677788899" You don't actually say where the numbers are coming from or in what form. If they're arriving one at a time from some other process or thread then you simply need to remember the last one and check if the latest is the same or different.

Comment: the number are from moving coordinate in a video, I try to explain it in from an example. your code work if the number 1111222334445556667788999111222333444455566677788899.. but if the number like this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-6VaPu2QKyKbkhSUld6UTRNbmc/edit how can I solve with this condition?

Answer (score -1):

Lets assume that you have the numbers as a string.

Let the string be str be comprising of all these numbers.
I'll propose a code in c.

```
 int count=0,flag=0;
 for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
     if(flag==0){
         if(str[i]=='4'){
            count=count+1;
            flag=1;
            continue;
         }
     }
     if(flag==1 && str[i]=='4')
        continue;
     flag=0;
  }
  printf("%d\n",count);
```

Count is the answer to your problem.

Comment: it work! then how about I want count number 4 and 7 in condition like before?